# How to search for files containing a particular text with Ansible?

Tags: grep, find, ansible, command

I'd like to know if there's an Ansible module other than `command` that will give me a list of files (recursive search) containing a pattern?

On Unix I'd do

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l pattern {} \;
```

The result would be a list of files I'd iterate to change a value  with another value

Comment: I was also tempted to mention the `shell` module :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [find module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/find_module.html) to do this. The `contains` parameter accepts a regex to search for file content:

```
- name: Find files
  find:
    paths: /var/log
    contains: pattern
  register: found_files
```

The result of the `find` modules contains the attributes `files`, with a list of the matched files, and `matched`, with the number of matched files. You can store the result by using the `register` attribute on the `find` command (`found_files` above).