# How to make Ansible with_fileglob work recursively for all subdirectories or alternative?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible and have a directory structure like the example below:

```
configs
  something
     files
         1.conf
         2.conf
         // and so on
```

Those files are templates and I am using Ansible to parse these templates and create them automatically in the destination server.

My problem is that `with_fileglob` is working only of first level directory and cannot seem to enable some recursive mode.

I have

```yaml
- name: "Apply templates"
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ item | replace('.j2', '') }}"
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{ user_configs_path }}/*"
```

by the way `user_configs_path=configs` exists and all good here.

The above does nothing.

If I add something under configs, example `configs/blabla.j2` and re-run the playbook it is parsed and copied fine.

So seems somehow that the directories are not searched recursively.

I am not limited to only use the `fileglob` solution so feel free to suggest anything I can learn to reach my goal.

Basically I want to recursively iterate all directories for `files only`, and in a loop apply the template module to them and create them in remote server

Answer (score 3):

[Ansible has a filetree](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/lookup/filetree.html) that is recursive.

Unlike glob, `item` is not just a string, but an object. You'd need to use `item.src` (absolute) and `item.path` (relative) to get the filename out of it.

Because `filetree` will also list directories, you need to add a `when` filter so that it only gives you the files back.

```
- name: "Apply templates"
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.path | replace('.j2', '') }}"
  with_filetree: "{{ user_configs_path }}/"
  when: item.state == 'file'
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> *My problem is that `with_fileglob` is working only of first level directory and cannot seem to enable some recursive mode.*

and according the documentation [`fileglob`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html#synopsis)

> *Matches all files in a single directory, non-recursively, that match a pattern. It calls Python’s “glob” library.*

for

> *How to make Ansible `with_fileglob` work recursively for all subdirectories*

one would need to enhance [the module code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/fileglob.py).

---

Regarding

> *Basically I want to recursively iterate all directories for files only, and in a loop apply the template module to them and create them in remote server*

as solution and depending on your requirements and what you try to achieve, you could use just

- [`find` module – Return a list of files based on specific criteria](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html), in example `.conf` files. It works with parameter `recursive: true` and will you provide with a list of full path(s) over which you can `loop` after.
- [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) like `find` and [`register: result`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible playbook to find out specific files in sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018387/)
- [Ansible: How to find latest files from a directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643396/)
- [How to search for files containing a particular text with Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667928/)

Comment: thanks that is fine. For this reason I asked in the end of question am open to alernate solutions might need change question title to exlcude with_fileglob

Comment: As an alternative solution you could use the `shell` module with `find`, `register: result` and proceed further with that.

Answer (score 1):

To add uppon the other answer.

## `file_glob` doesn't support `recursivity`

- `file_glob` from the doc, doesn't support recursive matching (unfortunately)
- you can't use `**`
- You have to use something else for recursive matching
- [Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html) ref

> Matches all files in a `single directory, non-recursively`, that match a pattern. It calls Python’s “glob” library.

## The options

- The best, ready to go => `with_community.general.filetree`

  - You would use `regex` for matching, instead of globs
  - Same thing for excluding (and yes we can and it's simple)
  - Will detail that below.
- `ansible.builtin.find`

  - Support `recursive` param and matching
  - find is find.
  - And you need to run two tasks too
- You can take `file_glob` lookup, copy, and build another lookup plugin, that extends the functionality and add `recursivity`. I don't see a reason, why recursivity wasn't implemented. After all, it does use `python` `glob()` under the hood.

  - Can be found here `.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible/plugins/lookup/fileglob.py`

    - See relatively to your installation (in here ansible is installed in the virtual env)
    - here a [github link too](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/fileglob.py)
  - Details at the end, and with a full implementation.
  - I wonder if there is a reason. I'll try with a PR. And update the answer if there are any updates.

## File matching `globs` and `regex`

- The main ways for file matching always been

  - Either `glob` system
  - Either `regex` system
- You can see that in many software. Many simply go with globs. Others go with regex. And many offer both.

  - jest does use regex ([example](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulepathignorepatterns-arraystring))

> Great with `with_community.general.filetree` we can use regex to it's extent. I'll show that next.

### Regex does have more power

- Globs generally are more simple, and have a good shorthand.
- Regex on the other hand, They are more rich, More powerful. And allow more complex patterns.

  - With regex, you can match against basically any pattern you want.
  - You can match against spcific characters only

    - `[abcd12345]+.ts`
    - `[a-z5-9]+.ts`
    - `\S+.ts`
    - The patterns are endless and from simple to two complex
    - You can also easily test in `regexr.com` or vscode search with `regex` mode activated (even offline).
    - For every glob operator. There is an equiv in regex. But not the inverse

## `with_community.general.filetree` and using regex for matching and excluding and to it's fullest

- match and exclude both are possible
- All get implemented by using `when` task attribute
- [Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/filetree_lookup.html)

Example from a project i was working on

```yaml
- name: Render templates in nginx_build folder (locally)
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: "{{ template_file.root }}/{{ template_file.path }}"
      dest: "{{ (site_ngx_conf_build_dir + '/' + template_file.path) | regex_replace('\\.j2', '') }}"
      mode: "0754"
    delegate_to: localhost
    # Old `fileglob`lookup that is not recursive (what a shame hhh)
    # loop: "{{ query('fileglob', site_ngx_conf_build_dir + '/**/*.j2') }}"
    with_community.general.filetree: "{{ site_ngx_conf_build_dir }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: template_file # only renaming var other than default `item`
    # Here go the matching
    when:
      - template_file.state != 'directory'
      # Match with regex

      # is truthy => to match
      - (template_file.path | regex_search('.+?\.j2$')) is truthy # match recursively anything that end with .j2

      # For union matching
      # - (
      #     ((template_file.path | regex_search(sub_path + '/some/.+?/doe/.+?\.j2$')) is truthy) or
      #     ((template_file.path | regex_search(sub_path + '/another/.+?\.j2$')) is truthy)
      #   )

      # For matching no recursively, only a one folder (you can use that with union above if you want)
      # - (template_file.path | regex_search('some/[^\/]+?\.j2$')) is truthy

      # is falsy => to exclude
      - (template_file.path | regex_search('certificates_ref_only')) is falsy
      # In short regex allow us to just match anything we want
```

- In my real project i needed to recurse cross all files that end with `.j2` (template files)

  - I only need

```yaml
- (item.path | regex_search('.+?\.j2$')) is truthy # match recursively anything that end with .j2
```

### `regex_search()` for regex

```yaml
- (item.path | regex_search('.+?\.j2$')) is truthy
```

- you can see how we set the base

### `when` and multiple conditions list

The `when` list is the equiv of `and`, the intersection of the conditions. One of the all is falsy, the whole is falsy.

```yaml
- condition is truthy # matching
- another is truthy # ???
```

- A list is basically

```py
(
  (condition is truthy) and
  (another is truthy)
)
```

- That would be true only if both of them match. Creating intersection of the two, not union.

  - `true` and `false` = `false` (not union)
  - only `true` and `true` = `true`
- Taking that away from the way. We can establish this

  - Inclusion you can have only one el in that list

    - For union, we use a block with `or` (details below)
  - Exclusion, you can have multiple one (because of the `and` )

    - `false` and `true` = `false`

      - one excluding, will be effective in all cases
      - Making multiple ones, a union for exclusion

In short:

```yaml
- one match condition # [optionally with `or or or ...` construct ]
- exclusion 1 # |
- exclusion 2 # |
- exclusion 3 # |
- exclusion 4 # |_ union of exclusion
```

### Inclusion and exclusion

- `is truthy` for inclusion
- `is falsy` for exclusion

```py
when:
  # Match with regex
  # is truthy => to match
  - (item.path | regex_search('.+?\.j2$')) is truthy # match recursively anything that end with .j2
  # is falsy => to exclude
  - (item.path | regex_search('certificates_ref_only')) is falsy
  # In short regex allow us to just match anything we want
```

### Inclusion union

```py
- (
    ((item.path | regex_search(sub_path + '/some/.+?/doe/.+?\.j2$')) is truthy) or
    ((item.path | regex_search(sub_path + '/another/.+?\.j2$')) is truthy)
  )
```

- always remember that the logical operators (`or` `and` ..) have a high precedence

  - Hince it's important to have `(firstInclusion) or (secondInclusion)`
  - Inclusion union is as simple as that.

### Regex equiv of globs

- many of characters that regex special => you need to escape them

  - `.` => `\.` (because `.` in regex mean any char except return character)
  - `^` => `\^`
  - `$` => `\$` ( `$` in regex mean end of line)
  - `[` => `\[`
  - `]` => `\]`
  - `/` => generally doesn't need escaping. But if it was used in a regex scope delimiter like `/regexPattern/g` => you'll need to escape it in that case `\/`

    - If you escape it. It would work in both cases. Generally in `'some/pattern'` context. I prefer to not escape. (cleaner)
  - ... (the list can be long)
- `**` or `**/*` => `.+?` [match a succession of chars, and one at least]

  - and regex has `.*?` extra, that matches a char or none (I wonder how to do that in glob)
  - recursive
  - `some/path/**/*.lsm` => `some/path/.*?\.lsm$`
  - `some/path/**/some/**/another/**/*.lsm` => `some/path/.*?/some/.*?/another/.*\.lsm$`
  - `**/*` match `.*?` because `**` can be nothing (sub dir or none)

[image]

- In regex, if you want to match against the end you should use `$`
- Otherwise, it can not be at the end, and it would match it. So be careful.

  - Generally, you should use `$` always (glob equiv). Unless you know what you are doing.
- Same for the start `^`
- For a path from start to end `^matching_pattern_in_between$`
- Use always in most cases `^some/path/pattern/here$`

  - We need to use them when we want to match an exact path from start to end (the glob mode by design). If we don't the pattern matches a substring. Even if it's not the full path. It will be matched. And you may not want that.
- We can use `^` or `$` only if we want to match the start part only or the end part only. ex `(item.path | regex_search('\.j2$')) is truthy` caring about matching the end only. Anything ending with `.j2` will be matched automatically. We don't even need `.+`.
- `*` ??? what about no recursive? => `[^/]*?`
- See next section

### Regex (`.+` or `.*`) is recursive by nature. So how do we do no recursive

- We should use

```yaml
[^/]+?
```

- Which means a succession of any character different from `/`

  - In the context of paths, that should suffice
  - You can choose to not have spaces chars if you want with `[^/\s]+?` ...
  - If you want to match a set of chars or none use `*` instead of `+` => `[^/]*?`
  - So it match till it reach `/` if doesn't fit the pattern. It's not a match. Just what `*` is.

Example

```py
# For matching no recursively, only one folder (you can use that with union above if you want)
- (item.path | regex_search(site_ngx_conf_build_dir + '/[^/]+?\.j2$')) is truthy
```

### `item.path` and `filetree`

- Remember that `item.path` is relative to the base you passed to `filetree`.

  - All apply starting relatively form there
  - Same for `^some/path/pattern/here$`

    - When we use `^$` we do it using relative paths. And we need to use them when we want to match an exact path from start to end. If we don't and if the pattern matches a sub-string. Even if it's not the full path. It will be matched. And you may not want that.

I guess that does cover the fundamentals of using regex for matching and matching with `with_community.general.filetree`. If you are already all familiar with regex. Than you already know all.

### `filetree` matches `files`, `directories` and `links`

- `item.state`

  - `file`
  - `directory`
  - `link`

Remember to match only files and links and not directories.

Add

```yaml
- item.state != 'directory'
```

or

```yaml
- item.state == 'file'
```

to the `when` list. I prefer to add it as the first one.

## Extending `fileglob` implementation

This is the python glob definition, by default `recursive mode` is disabled

```py
def glob(pathname, *, root_dir=None, dir_fd=None, recursive=False,
        include_hidden=False):
```

And in the `fileglob.py` you find `glob()` used like this

```py
for dwimmed_path in found_paths:
    if dwimmed_path:
        globbed = glob.glob(to_bytes(os.path.join(dwimmed_path, term_file), errors='surrogate_or_strict'))
        term_results = [to_text(g, errors='surrogate_or_strict') for g in globbed if os.path.isfile(g)]
        if term_results:
            ret.extend(term_results)
            break
```

### Simple and may be efficient in extending

All that needs to be done is:

- converting

```py
globbed = glob.glob(to_bytes(os.path.join(dwimmed_path, term_file), errors='surrogate_or_strict'))
```

to

```py
globbed = glob.glob(to_bytes(os.path.join(dwimmed_path, term_file), errors='surrogate_or_strict', recursive=True))
```

I would maybe even add

```py
include_hidden=True
```

> That would make a version, that supports recursivity and doesn't need any params. Just use `**/*` for recursivity.

### May be better to extend by adding optional options

Which one is better I wonder. But here is how we can set `file_glob` lookup with optional `options` that we pass to it.

- To do that, we have a great example at [url() lookup script](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/8a5ccc9d63ab528b579c14c4519c70c6838c7d6c/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/url.py#L225)

to set the options we use

```py
class LookupModule(LookupBase):

    def run(self, terms, variables=None, **kwargs):

        self.set_options(var_options=variables, direct=kwargs)
```

And for getting the options

```py
response = open_url(
    term, validate_certs=self.get_option('validate_certs'),
    use_proxy=self.get_option('use_proxy'),
    url_username=self.get_option('username'),
    url_password=self.get_option('password'),
    headers=self.get_option('headers'),
    force=self.get_option('force'),
    timeout=self.get_option('timeout'),
    http_agent=self.get_option('http_agent'),
```

And for final lookup usage, it would be something like

```yaml
- name: url lookup splits lines by default
  ansible.builtin.debug: msg="{{item}}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.url', 'https://github.com/gremlin.keys', wantlist=True) }}"

- name: display ip ranges
  ansible.builtin.debug: msg="{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.url', 'https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json', split_lines=False) }}"
```

All from that same `url.py` file. And we can do the same with `fileglob`.

- I'll try to make a PR, and see if it would get accepted.
- If you add your own plugin, you will need to create a folder called `lookup_plugins` at the same level of your playbook. Otherwise use `lookup_plugins={{ ANSIBLE_HOME ~ "/plugins/lookup:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/lookup:our_ansible/lookup_plugins" }}` setting in `ansible.cfg`

  - Refs:

    - [Developing plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html)
    - [lockup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#enabling-lookup-plugins)

### The full implementations to copy

- To not make this answer any longer, here is a GitHub repo, that contains the modified implementation.

  - https://github.com/MohamedLamineAllal/ansible-fileglob-lockup-extended
  - The options version, I'll add it tomorrow. (I had a long day)

### Notes

- For the implementations, I haven't checked them yet. I will in the next day. And update after
- Also I didn't evaluate enough why, why the core team limited it to be `not recursive`. I don't see a reason without giving it much of thinking. I'll evaluate it better update that and see about a PR.
- Same for checking ansible issues track.